# Ubuntu 11.10 won't detect my second monitor

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors

When Ubuntu boots, the second monitor mirrors my other monitor, but when the login screen pops up, the monitor doesn't get any signal from my computer. When I go to monitor setup, it is not detected. If I unplug my first monitor, the second works fin with Ubuntu. When I tried 11.10 on a flash drive, it worked fine as a dual monitor. The default seems to be VGA over the DVI connection. Help?

Comment: you need to provide more information - what video card and which monitor.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Nvidia card:
install your drivers by opening Additional Drivers and installing the recommended option. Then, try checking out the settings in "nvidia-settings". Go into the Display Configuration category and make sure that neither of your monitors are disabled. If so, change them to TwinView.